# android contact source code com.android.contacts

Tags: android

i am trying to understand android adding new contact functionality, problem is android.git.kernel.org is down i googled n found other resources for the source code of andriod os

[Github](http://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java)

[Google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android-cookbook/source/browse/trunk/OilCan/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java?r=18)

[Gitorious.com](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_contacts/blobs/0bfe3a15d9996bd0be4003b586a9f4b3d68b3ea6/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java)

but unable to understand it completely

i am looking for the code when on android we click on new contact and that screen or activity contains + and - buttons to add field and delete field dynamically, because i need the same functionality for my project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in `EditContactActivity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, please tell me one more thing how you studied and how you find this particular functionality is in this particular file, i tried google but didnt get any success.